# Reprojecting from Clarke_1880_RGS_Lambert_Conformal_Conic to ETRS_1989_LAEA?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system

I am unable to reproject Marseille shapefiles from Clarke 1880 RGS_Lambert_Conformal_Conic to ETRS_1989_LAEA.

I know that Clarke is a geographic coordinate system and it has no datum.  I have tried varying different things (project to ED50 utm zone 31N, ED79, WGS84) but it seems that ArcGIS does not do anything ... the data always remains in the same place.

The funny thing is that I have one shapefile in GCS_Clarke_1880_IGN that projected well to ETRS89 on the fly.

Comment: Can you share part of the data with points or lines recognizable in other maps?

Comment: Well.. I am just displaying that data.. but I can see how the data is displayed wrongly...  as the reference data Marseille city appears far far away...

Comment: That can be due to false Easting or false Northing, or some other parameters missing or wrong in the .prj file.

Comment: Yes I think so.. But how can I change it manually?

Comment: I don't work with ARCGIS, but this should help: http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00560000000r000000

Answer (score 2):

Note: I'm moving information that the original poster included in a comment to this answer.

> After tons of attempts, I solved it. Basically, my data is wrongly
>   projected initially. The Clarke 1880 RGS_Lambert_Conformal_Conic
>   projection is wrong. I put a map in the background and the data was
>   drawn in Norway. understoood that the problem was this initial
>   projection. How can people link wrong projections to data??? I found
>   NTF_Lambert_Zone_III to be the right one.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem in the past, because the datum of the clarke was in fact based on the meridian of Paris and used grade (square angle = 100) instead of degrees. This could explain your large shift. Is your "far far away" difference en X close to the distance between Greenwich and Paris ?

You could then try with this datum :   GCS_NTF_Paris , making sure to set a transform in your data frame properties > coordinate system.

Clarke_IGN is in degrees and based on greenwich, so there is not a big difference with ETRS 89 (yet there is a "small" one, be carefull)

Comment: I tried with GCS_NTF PAris but the data is not moved. I deleted the prj file first to avoid errots but nothing happens. Lil bit desperated now. :(

Comment: you must not delete your prj, otherwise the transform will not work. try posting your data (or at least the prj) so the community can have a try. At least, edit your question with the copy-pasted prj.

Comment: ok.. This is the projection that im looking for:                                                       Projected Coordinate System: ETRS_1989_LAEA
Projection: Lambert_Azimuthal_Equal_Area
False_Easting: 4321000.00000000
False_Northing: 3210000.00000000
Central_Meridian: 10.00000000
Latitude_Of_Origin: 52.00000000
Linear Unit:  Meter

Geographic Coordinate System: GCS_ETRS_1989
Datum:  D_ETRS_1989
Prime Meridian:  Greenwich
Angular Unit:  Degree

Comment: this is the one my origina data has:                        Projected Coordinate System: Clarke_1880_RGS_Lambert_Conformal_Conic
Projection: Lambert_Conformal_Conic
False_Easting: 600000.00000000
False_Northing: 200000.00000000
Central_Meridian: 2.33722917
Standard_Parallel_1: 43.19929139
Standard_Parallel_2: 44.99609389
Latitude_Of_Origin: 44.10000000
Linear Unit:  Meter

Geographic Coordinate System: GCS_Clarke_1880_RGS
Datum:  D_Clarke_1880_RGS
Prime Meridian:  Greenwich
Angular Unit:  Degree

Comment: this is the one of another shapefile.. that on the fly works:                                                      Lambert Conformal Conic
Projection: Lambert_Conformal_Conic
False_Easting: 600000.00000000
False_Northing: 200000.00000000
Central_Meridian: 2.33722917
Standard_Parallel_1: 45.89891889
Standard_Parallel_2: 47.69601444
Latitude_Of_Origin: 46.80000000
Linear Unit:  Meter

Geographic Coordinate System: GCS_Clarke_1880_IGN
Datum:  D_Clarke_1880_IGN
Prime Meridian:  Greenwich
Angular Unit:  Degree

Comment: After tons of attempts.. I solved it. Basically, my data is wrongly projected initially. The Clarke 1880 RGS_Lambert_Conformal_Conic projection is wrong... I put a map in the background and the data was drawn in Norway..  understoood that the problem was this initial projection.. How can people link wrong projections to data??? I found NTF_Lambert_Zone_III to be the right one...

Thanks to everyone

Comment: You should post this information as the answer!